# Odoo: Submit custom field from Sale Order to Stock Picking

Tags: python, odoo

I have a Problem. I use Odoo 9 Enterprise on Debian 8. I added a custom field each to sales Order and Stock Pickings. The field is called Technician.

When I make a sales Order I want to specify, which Technician has to check the goods, while stock picking. This Information needs to go to the Stock Picking Entry in the Inventory.

Can anybody help me how to achieve this?

Cheers,
Niklas